# Changing dateformat in stockcharts from amchart

Tags: charts, date-format, amcharts, stock

I created a stockchart from amchart and saved it here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5pxpt8cj/1/)

Now I want to change (a) the date format of the chart cursor to "DD.MM.YYYY" and (b) the date format of the category axis to german format, e.g. "01. Mai 2018". I assume that (a) can somehow be solved with "categoryBalloonDateFormat", but I wasn't able to find the correct place to put it.

```
chart.ChartCursor.categoryBalloonDateFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY";
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

For (b) I have no clue at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a) you have to set it in the [`chartCursorSettings.categoryBalloonDateFormats`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/ChartCursorSettings#categoryBalloonDateFormats) array for the desired period(s) represented in your chart. If your data is daily, at least set the DD and WW periods (daily and weekly), but depending on the amount of data, you might want to set the MM (monthly) period as well. For example:

```
chart.chartCursorSettings.categoryBalloonDateFormats = [
  {period:"YYYY", format:"YYYY"},
  {period:"MM", format:"MMM, YYYY"},
  {period:"WW", format:"DD.MM.YYYY"},
  {period:"DD", format:"DD.MM.YYYY"}, 
  {period:"hh", format:"JJ:NN"},
  {period:"mm", format:"JJ:NN"},
  {period:"ss", format:"JJ:NN:SS"},
  {period:"fff", format:"JJ:NN:SS"}
]
```

Similarly for (b), you have to set the [`categoryAxesSettings.dateFormats`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxesSettings#dateFormats) array in the same manner as `categoryBalloonDateFormats`:

```
chart.categoryAxesSettings.dateFormats = [
  {period:"YYYY", format:"YYYY"},
  {period:"MM", format:"MMM, YYYY"},
  {period:"WW", format:"DD.MM.YYYY"},
  {period:"DD", format:"DD.MM.YYYY"}, 
  {period:"hh", format:"JJ:NN"},
  {period:"mm", format:"JJ:NN"},
  {period:"ss", format:"JJ:NN:SS"},
  {period:"fff", format:"JJ:NN:SS"}
]
```

Demo:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "stock",
  "theme": "light",

  "categoryAxesSettings": {
    "dateFormats": [{
        period: "YYYY",
        format: "YYYY"
      },
      {
        period: "MM",
        format: "DD.MM.YYYY"
      },
      {
        period: "WW",
        format: "DD.MM.YYYY"
      },
      {
        period: "DD",
        format: "DD.MM.YYYY"
      },
      {
        period: "hh",
        format: "JJ:NN"
      },
      {
        period: "mm",
        format: "JJ:NN"
      },
      {
        period: "ss",
        format: "JJ:NN:SS"
      },
      {
        period: "fff",
        format: "JJ:NN:SS"
      }
    ]
  },

  "chartCursorSettings": {
    "categoryBalloonDateFormats": [{
        period: "YYYY",
        format: "YYYY"
      },
      {
        period: "MM",
        format: "DD.MM.YYYY"
      },
      {
        period: "WW",
        format: "DD.MM.YYYY"
      },
      {
        period: "DD",
        format: "DD.MM.YYYY"
      },
      {
        period: "hh",
        format: "JJ:NN"
      },
      {
        period: "mm",
        format: "JJ:NN"
      },
      {
        period: "ss",
        format: "JJ:NN:SS"
      },
      {
        period: "fff",
        format: "JJ:NN:SS"
      }
    ],
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": true
  },

  "dataSets": [{
    "fieldMappings": [{
      "fromField": "value",
      "toField": "value"
    }],

    "dataProvider": generateChartData(),
    "categoryField": "date"
  }],

  "panels": [{
    "stockGraphs": [{
      "valueField": "value",
      "type": "smoothedLine"
    }]
  }]
});


function generateChartData() {
  var chartData = [];
  var firstDate = new Date(2012, 0, 1);
  firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 1000);
  firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
    newDate.setDate(i);

    var a = Math.round(Math.random() * (40 + i)) + 100 + i;

    chartData.push({
      date: newDate,
      value: a
    });
  }
  return chartData;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - that worked! In addition if someone wants to change the month names to another language:

```
AmCharts.monthNames = [
              'Januar',
              'Februar',
              'März',
              'April',
              'Mai',
              'Juni',
              'Juli',
              'August',
              'September',
              'Oktober',
              'November',
              'Dezember'];
            AmCharts.shortMonthNames = [
              'Jan.',
              'Feb.',
              'März',
              'April',
              'Mai',
              'Juni',
              'Juli',
              'Aug.',
              'Sept.',
              'Okt.',
              'Nov.',
              'Dez.'];
```